# android m preview 3 app crash with permission CONNECTIVITY_INTERVAL

Tags: android, exception, crash, connectivity, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my application I am using `wifimanager` and internet. It's crashing on `Preview3 Android Marshmallow`. It's giving following exception.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10057
        nor current process has android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL.
```

If anyone has faced this issue and fixed. Please help in fixing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can not add that permission in manifest as it is System level permission.Its crashing when I am calling ConnectivityManager requestNetwork method.I have to fix this as soon as possible.I am not getting any idea why its happening.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the permission management capabilities are not present in preview 3 but are available in the recently released images (e.g. in https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) . I suggest you install one on your device and look in Apps->Settings for the capabilities you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error with android M preview 3.

In my app I use ConnectivityManager to call requestNetwork() function

```
requestNetwork(NetworkRequest, NetworkCallback)
```

For building the NetworkRequest I use this code

```
android.net.NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new android.net.NetworkRequest.Builder();
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    builder.removeTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
```

After adding capability parameters, the crash was gone

```
android.net.NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new android.net.NetworkRequest.Builder();
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    builder.removeTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
```